# Site moved to new server, now getting premature end of script headers error on exports

Tags: php, kohana

I've been migrating an old clients site (Kohana 2.3) from one of my servers to an third party server and am now getting a premature end of script headers error when I either attempt to export data from my database or attempt to send emails to my clients after about 30-40 seconds of processing.

I've attempted increasing the php.ini to raise my maximum memory limit and and maximum time limit both to no avail, producing the same error.

I attempted to manually reduce the number of elements that would be exported and got it to run the script without erroring for something between 700-750 elements, but this goes up and down whenever I run the script. The live data that I'm using contains over 5000 elements.

Running memory_get_peak_usage returns that I'm using a maximum of a bit under 16M of memory to execute these scripts, so I'm reasonably sure that I'm not going over any memory limits as my php memory limit is 256M.

Setting the time limit in php to 5 seconds will generate a timeout error instead of a premature end of scripts error, but, this being expected, is not helpful.

The strange thing is that nothing is being written to any logs. I've checked the php logs, the Kohana logs and the apache logs, and there is nothing that seems to point me in a direction of what could be causing this issue.

I was wondering if anyone had encountered this before or had any ideas with where I should go with this.

Comment: Turned out to be a max CPU time limit issue. The code was exceeding the RLIMIT_CPU. Raising this allowed the export to run without hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a /var/log/apache/suexec.log file; if so, and if it's the problem, it'll explain the reason why it's denying your script from executing properly.  One easy fix to try is adding a "-w" to the end of the first line of your Perl script, i.e. change the first line from "#!/usr/bin/perl" to "#!/usr/bin/perl -w" and see if that makes suEXEC happy.  Another common fix is to make sure that your CGI script has the same user/group ownership as your cgi-bin folder.